# how to get matched records from two input files with different length of both files in awk?

Tags: awk

Input file

```
file 1==HQ|SCORE
file 2==HQ|WRST_PMT_STAT|total_exposure
```

Output file

```
HQ|WRST_PMT_STAT|total_exposure|SCORE
```

IN that both files common is `HQ`

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{c[$1]++;next};c[$1]' File1 file2 > output
```

i am getting only file2 input i am not getting `SCORE`. both files contains 60k records.

Comment: You can get the desired output with ```echo "HQ|WRST_PMT_STAT|total_exposure|SCORE"```.  If you want a solution that’s based on the input, please *explain* the relationship between the input and the output, and, ideally, give a few more examples. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with below command

```
awk -F "|" 'NR==FNR {b[FNR]=$2;a[$1];next}($1 in a){print $0"|"b[FNR]}' file1 file2
```

output

```
HQ|WRST_PMT_STAT|total_exposure|SCORE
```